PySide6: "libc++abi: Pure virtual function called!" instead of error info in log
I see strange behaviour in PySide6 (v6.7.0) app.
When an error occurs, I see only "libc++abi: Pure virtual function called!" in console log. Which is not very informative and slows down the development
However, if is set pdb breakpoint before the problematic line and step through the code, python log message is displayed with more meaningful message (e.g. "object has no attribute")
In system crash log, I see:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib                 0x1880095f0 __pthread_kill + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x188041c20 pthread_kill + 288
2   libsystem_c.dylib                      0x187f4ea30 abort + 180
3   libc++abi.dylib                        0x187ff8d08 abort_message + 132
4   libc++abi.dylib                        0x187ff86e0 __cxa_pure_virtual + 24
5   QtCore                                 0x104a8fe10 QAbstractAnimationPrivate::setState(QAbstractAnimation::State) + 1388
6   QtCore                                 0x104993f04 0x1048c4000 + 851716
7   QtCore                                 0x104a8febc QAbstractAnimationPrivate::setState(QAbstractAnimation::State) + 1560
8   QtCore                                 0x104a98e14 QPropertyAnimation::~QPropertyAnimation() + 32
9   QtCore.abi3.so                         0x1043e0a00 QPropertyAnimationWrapper::~QPropertyAnimationWrapper() + 56
10  QtCore                                 0x104a94cdc 0x1048c4000 + 1903836
11  QtCore                                 0x104a94be4 QAnimationGroup::~QAnimationGroup() + 40
12  QtCore.abi3.so                         0x1043d54c8 QParallelAnimationGroupWrapper::~QParallelAnimationGroupWrapper() + 56
13  libshiboken6.abi3.6.7.dylib            0x102e5b9a4 SbkDeallocWrapperCommon(_object*, bool) + 344
14  Python                                 0x103063678 dictkeys_decref + 172
15  Python                                 0x1030668c0 dict_dealloc + 240
16  libshiboken6.abi3.6.7.dylib            0x102e601dc Shiboken::Object::deallocData(SbkObject*, bool) + 404
17  libshiboken6.abi3.6.7.dylib            0x102e5b92c SbkDeallocWrapperCommon(_object*, bool) + 224
18  Python                                 0x103098b8c subtype_dealloc + 744
19  libshiboken6.abi3.6.7.dylib            0x102e5f90c Shiboken::Object::destroy(SbkObject*, void*) + 232
20  QtWidgets.abi3.so                      0x1070efbf8 QGraphicsViewWrapper::~QGraphicsViewWrapper() + 56
21  QtCore                                 0x10498b834 QObjectPrivate::deleteChildren() + 152
22  QtWidgets                              0x1090bd190 QWidget::~QWidget() + 1172
23  QtWidgets.abi3.so                      0x106dd1890 QWidgetWrapper::~QWidgetWrapper() + 64
24  libshiboken6.abi3.6.7.dylib            0x102e5b9a4 SbkDeallocWrapperCommon(_object*, bool) + 344

Any ideas how to get python crash report are appreciated.

please provide a MRE
